# How can I trigger an update of the manifest.json file in an installed progressive web app on Android?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I recently deployed a progressive web app using Create React App. Everything seems to be working fine, but it looks like the latest version of my manifest.json file isn't being updated.

Under what conditions does Chrome request the latest version of manifest.json for installed web apps using the new WebAPK-based Add to homescreen?